# Excel 2016 - JSON web query - extra characters at the end of JSON input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel-2016

I am trying to return some data to Excel via my web server.

```
Function ReturnSomeJson(id As String) As JsonResult
    Return Json(DataProvider.GetSomeData(id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

If i now go `New Query -> From File -> From JSON` enter the url `http://localhost:666/ReturnSomeJson/666`, it tries to open it but i get the following error message:

> Details: "We found extra characters at the end of JSON input."

There's nothing wrong with the JSON, anyone encountered this before or have ideas to get round this in another way easily?

Comment: Have you tried using `From other sources -> From Web`?

Comment: Tried the 'From web' one not in the 'Other sources' list, that didnt work and neither does this, i get 'it doesn't appear to be a webpage'

Comment: Can you try with this url - `http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd` - If it does work we know its an issue with the format of your JSON.

Comment: Hmm that works, but my JSON is valid according to http://jsonlint.com/, i saw something about putting line breaks in for excel to recognise it somewhere

Comment: Yes I was just reading this - https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/We-found-extra-characters-at-the-end-of-JSON-input/td-p/20607 - Try looking at your json and the json from above url in browser and comparing? Sorry it looks like it is going to be a Json format issue.

Comment: Barely any difference between ours, not comparing the string visually anyways, might be non-printing characters after the JSON. Tbh i was only going down this route as i thought it might be quick and easy.. might be time to backtrack

Comment: OK, one last thought - is it using lower case for the property names - has tripped me up before, needed to use `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`

Comment: No it's not using all lower case for property names, should it be?

Comment: Ah right ok, mine is coming out as cased on the .net side - i am using `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult` not newtonsoft

Comment: That's done it, if you want to wrap that up into an answer i will give it to you - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From above comments:

OK, one last thought - is it using lower case for the property names - has tripped me up before, needed to use `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`

e.g. if you look at this URL `http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd` - should be formatted as `{"id":"BE","type":"l","text":"Population"}` and NOT `{"Id":"BE","Type":"l","Text":"Population"}`

Answer (score 0):

This threat may be old, but I was trying to ingest an AWS CloudCheckr JSON into Excel via Power Query and getting the "We found extra characters at the end of JSON input."

**Finally figured out, with the help of https://jsonformatter.org/ that some data was provided as `True` -- without quotes, which Excel PQ needed.  Simple find/replacing `:True,` with `:"True",` did the trick.**

Seriously, Microsoft, you did not recognize Boolean when you found it?  Excel would have had no problem.